# How can I stop CSS validation errors appearing in the Errors List in VS2008

Tags: visual-studio-2008

For some reason in Visual Studio when I build my application it wants to validate my CSS and show those up as build errors in the error list. It's really really annoying as it makes it hard to find what the real build errors are. Is there any way to stop CSS validation errors showing up in the Errors List?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Look under Tools --> Options and find the CSS Editor options.  I think there are some options there that control whether errors and/or warnings are reported.  I don't have access to VS right now so I can't verify the exact options that are available.

Comment: For posterity, in Visual Studio 2010 it is Tools > Options (make sure "Show All Settings" is checked) > Text Editor > CSS > Miscellaneous. Then there will be a "Detect Errors" checkbox on the right. Unclick it and errors will stop.